# Differentiating a squared quantity

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwJJF.jpg]

I was reading through my electromagnetism book where i came across this statement where when we differentiate wrt a squared quantity rather than a single quantity we multiply it by $\frac{1}{2}$. How?

Comment: Note that this is *differentiating a squared quantity*, not *differentiating **with respect to** a squared quantity*.

Comment: I will make the change.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product rule for the dot product is
$$\frac{d}{dt}({\bf E}(t) \cdot {\bf F}(t)) = \frac{d}{dt} {\bf E}(t) \cdot {\bf F}(t) + {\bf E}(t) \cdot \frac{d}{dt}{\bf F}(t) ,$$
and specializing to ${\bf F} = {\bf E}$ gives
$$\frac{d}{dt}({\bf E}(t) \cdot {\bf E}(t)) = 2 {\bf E}(t) \cdot {\bf E}'(t) .$$
Note too that if we denote $E(t) := ||{\bf E}(t)||$, then ${\bf E}(t) \cdot {\bf E}(t) = E(t)^2$.

Comment: Thanks Travis... I got it now..

Comment: @user2961109 Great, I'm glad you found it useful.